# Can I make a external hard drive bootable with ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installation, hard-drive

Can I make a external hard drive bootable with ubuntu 13.04? The same way you would with a usb stick. I currently dont have my large memory stick big enough so can I install ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop by using an external hard drive to boot it from the install it the same way you would using a bootable usb stcik??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can , you have to make sure your external hard drive does not contain anything else other than the ISO image. If you know the process which you need to take for a flash disk, then you simply follow the same procedure i.e instruct your computer to boot from external sources. I would always recommend use of a CD.